# What is wrong with my plant? and why is it turning yellow?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, indoors

For some reason, my plant started turning yellow. At first, I thought maybe I'm over watering it, because I was watering once a week. Then I stopped watering for three weeks, and even though there are new leaves coming out, a lot of the green leaves have turned yellow. What can be the cause of the problem?

[image: Plant turning yellow]

[image: Leaf turning yellow]

Comment: Have you moved the plant recently to a sunnier spot? The almost white leaf looks like a sunburn as I observed it with lucky bamboo.

Comment: It was in a spot that received roughly 4 hours of direct sunlight. I then moved it to a spot that only received indirect light, but the situation got worse. That’s why I moved it to a spot that gets something like 1.5 hours of morning sunlight. No matter where I move it, some leaves turn yellow. There are new leaves sprouting so I don’t think the plant is dead, but something is clearly wrong.

Comment: Is it sitting in water at the base? I wonder if it has to do with root rot, or some kind of root damage. Since only some are bad and others look healthy, it makes me think that maybe the roots are damaged in some spots. Might be worth repotting and removing any dead roots.

Comment: Ok, I've repotted it to be sure. Some roots were indeed rotten, but I couldn't really separate them without damaging the healthy ones, so I just tried to shake the soil off of them and repotted with new soil. I've also added some stones on the bottom to help with draining. Let's hope it's better now.

Comment: Just here to report back that the plant is completely healthy now and everything is going well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The most common factors for yellowing money tree leaves are too much sunlight, wide range of temperature fluctuations throughout the day and/or over-watering. Do not leave yellowing leaves on until they turn brown since it can spread decay to other parts of the plant.

Answer (score 0):

Is the plant near a heat source or draft? I can't tell what it is, but in the top picture, bottom right hand corner I see a white-ish device that could be a heater. Be sure to protect your plants from heat sources or drafts as that could damage their leaves.